# How to estimate the sample needed to train the binary classification model?

Tags: classification, sample-size, sample

Let's say the population is 100 thousand, the share of the target variable is 1%. I found calculators that, based on the normal distribution, find to confirm a share of 1% and give an estimate of the sample size of 400 pieces - but this doesn’t seem to be the case. How else to approach the problem?

[image]
http://www.raosoft.com/samplesize.html?nosurvey

My current approach to base the sample size on negative cases that might be around 400 pieces plus 100 sample to test and validate the model. Making total size around 50k.

Comment: I don't follow all of your explanation, which is a bit telegraphed, and I can't tell whether you are using logistic regression, estimating a simple proportion, or trying for something else.  But I don't think the calculator you referenced is going to be the right one.  The open-source GPower program might help.